# Feature Request: Careers filter by tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

On http://careers.stackoverflow.com, allow me to display results of job postings based on tags, both tags that I'm tracking and tags that I'm filtering out.

The functionality would look like the functionality that is already on StackOverflow for questions, but with one caveat.

The tag filter would ignore all the technology topics that are mentioned in the nice-to-have category (that employers sometimes mention).  In other words, as an Android java mobile developer, I would love to filter out iOS, C#, NDK, titanium, and HTML5 when I track jobs for Android, but obviously iOS wouldn't matter to me if it was only mentioned as a nice-to-have requirement.

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the detailed request! It sounds like this has several components: ability to track tags, listing of jobs matching your tracked tags on the homepage, and ability for employers to indicate certain tags are nice-to-have.

We are actually already moving in this general direction. We are preparing to build an experimental homepage view that displays the jobs that best match your Stack Overflow activity, using some of the new [job targeting infrastructure](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/) we recently rolled out. We are also reworking our job search to run on Elasticsearch, rather than SQL Server full-text indexing, which should bring with it more powerful querying capabilities. Finally, we have been kicking around ideas for a news feed that would be influenced by the searches you are tracking (as in, subscribed to by email). Generally speaking, we have increased our focus on improving the developer experience in recent months and we will continue this trend for the foreseeable future.

Because of these efforts already in the pipeline, we will not be able to build your specific request, but we do look forward to receiving your feedback as these new features roll out.